# How to change the order of fields in the Drupal Commerce Checkout Form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am using Drupal Commerce 7.x. I have added some fields to the checkout form in the customer profile. Specifically I've added 'Title' and 'Organization'. I'd like to move some of the fields around because they aren't in the order I'd like, but I can't figure out how to move them.

For example, right now the order is: 1. Country (I def. don't want that first) 2. Full name 3. Address etc.

I want it like this:
    City

```
Full Name

Title (new field)

Organization (new field)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) to change the checkout form. The form id you are look for would be `commerce_checkout_form_checkout`. By adding/adjusting the [`#weight`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#weightval) properties of the fields, you can manipulate the order of the fields. Fields with lower numbers appear before those with higher numbers.